# How get incremented major version from one configuration to another

Tags: teamcity

I have two configurations of build in the TeamCity. First for PreRelease builds with a minor counter version in *Build number format* and a Release configuration with a `major counting version`.

Also I have a preConf build variable custom, for now it is set as 2.

When I start build a Release build counter has incremented to *2.1* version. And now I need get this result of version in a PreRelease configuration for adding a minor version *2.1.1*, for example.

How can I do that better? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using dependencies(snapshot or artefact). You basically need to set target 2 as a dependency of target 1

In such a case, you can access any variable set in previous build (i.e target 1  ) in the dependent build  target2 using the form `%dep.<buildID>.varname%`

You can read more on this [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-DependenciesProperties).